# Automate cut and paste charts into powerpoint from excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

All,

I have charts in excel, that I need to paste as image into powerpoint and then resize and position. They are all pretty much the same chart and slide (although with different data and with different metrics in call-out boxes, which I would like to populate automatically as well). How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

-Rik

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried simply recording a macro, and doing these tasks manually? This will provide you with the initial building blocks of creating an automated macro yourself.

Comment: I don't have a macro recorder in powerpoint on the developer tab, not sure how to get it there...

Comment: Macro record is on the review ribbon, not the developer ribbon (I don't know why).

Comment: There's no macro recorder in PowerPoint any longer.  There used to be a way of customizing a macro recorder button onto one or another of the ribbon tabs, but it wouldn't do much, if it would do anything at all.  It's gone.